# Change the priority of python sys.path

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I change the priority of the path in sys.path in python 2.7?
I know that I can use `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, but it is what I will get:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=/tmp python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> for i in sys.path:
...   print i
... 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycuda-2014.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytest-2.6.2-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytools-2014.3-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py-1.4.24-py2.7.egg
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/tmp
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client
>>>
```

`/tmp` is added between `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` and `/usr/lib/python2.7`.

My goal is to make python to load packages from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` first.

Here is what I want:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.version
<module 'numpy.version' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/version.pyc'>
>>>
```

If I install `python-numpy` by `apt-get install python-numpy`. Python will try to load from `/usr/lib/python2.7` and not the one I compiled.

Comment: From the outputs you provided python *is* loading modules from `/usr/local` before those in `/usr/lib` so, where's the problem?

Comment: Have you tried simply editing the variable sys.path to see if that works?

Comment: @Bakuriu no. I remove the installed numpy by "apt-get remove python-numpy" to get this result for asking the solution.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Yes, but the change is not permanent.

Comment: Well you could put it in your $PYTHONSTARTUP file, then it would be "permanent" in the same way that modifying $PYTHONPATH would be.

Comment: Note that what you are seeing is due to the implicit [`import site`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/site.html) done during initialization. If you launch the interpreter with the `-S` options you'll see that `/tmp` is added at the beginning of the list instead of among the other paths.

Comment: Thanks. $PYTHONSTARTUP seems work for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you may know, [`sys.path` is initialized from](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

- the current directory
- your `PYTHONPATH`
- an installation-dependent default

However unfortunately that is only part of the story: `setuptools` creates [`easy-install.pth`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html) files, which also modify `sys.path` and worst of all they *prepend* packages and therefore totally mess up the order of directories.

In particular (at least on my system), there is `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy-install.pth` with the following contents:

```
import sys; sys.__plen = len(sys.path)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
import sys; new=sys.path[sys.__plen:]; del sys.path[sys.__plen:]; p=getattr(sys,'__egginsert',0); sys.path[p:p]=new; sys.__egginsert = p+len(new)
```

This causes `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` to be *prepended even before your `PYTHONPATH`*!

What you could do is simply change the 2nd line in this file to

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

and you will get your desired priority.

However beware this file might be overwritten or changed again by a future `setuptools` invocation!

Answer (score 2):

We encountered an almost identical situation and wanted to expand upon @kynan's response which is spot-on.  In the case where you have such an `easy-install.pth`  that you want to overcome, but which you cannot modify it (say you are a user with no root/admin access), you can do the following:

- Set up an [alternate python installation scheme](https://docs.python.org/3/install/#alternate-installation)

  - e.g. we use a PYTHON HOME install (setting PYTHONUSERBASE)
- Create a user/home site-packages

  - You can do this by installing a package into the user env: `pip install <package> --user`
- Create a pth to set `sys.__egginsert` to workaround the system/distribution easy-install.pth

  - Create a `$PYTHONUSERBASE/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fix_easy_install.pth`
  - Containing: `import sys; sys.__egginsert = len(sys.path);`

This will set `sys.__egginsert` to point to the end of your `sys.path` including your usersite paths.  When the nefarious system/dist `easy-install.pth` will then insert its items at the end of the system path.