# Dynamically changing python import priority

Tags: python

I have a file tree that looks like this:

```
my_repo/
|-- main/
|   |-- my_script.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|-- common/
|   |-- utils.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|-- config/
|   |-- config.py
|   |-- __init__.py
```

and I have installed an external package with a file tree:

```
some_package
|-- setup.py
|-- config.py
...
```

After installing the package, by default running `import config` will import the module from `some_package`.

`my_script.py` needs to import `common/utils.py` which runs the following:

```
from config.config import SOME_VALUE
```

No matter how I try to rearange the imports path, I still get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config.config'; 'config' is not a package
```

The above error clearly means that we were able to find the `common` package in the path but `config` is still imported from `some_package`
Here are my attempts to import `common/utils.py` in `my_script.py`, all yielding the same result:

```
sys.path.append('..'); from common import utils
sys.path.append('..'); from common import utils
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/myuser/my_repo'); from common import utils
sys.path.insert(0, '..'); from common import utils
sys.__plen = len(sys.path); sys.path.append('..'); new=sys.path[sys.__plen:]; del sys.path[sys.__plen:]; p=getattr(sys,'__egginsert',0); sys.path[p:p]=new; sys.__egginsert = p+len(new); from common import utils
```

The last idea is take from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193193/change-the-priority-of-python-sys-path).

Anyone got any fresh ideas on how to give priority to *my* config package instead of the one from the external package?

My python version is 3.9.7.
Thanks

Comment: is there a way you can provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: And please include how you've installed `some_package`, as `import config` should not import a module from inside a package.

Comment: "sys.modules" contains all already imported modules. On import Python looks it up first. It can help to manipulate it.

Comment: reproduce using: https://github.com/guyazran/mystery_issue/tree/master/my_repo.

installed "some_package" by
cd some_package;
python setup.py build develop

Answer (score 0):

Add `path-to-project-root/my_repo` to your [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) before to run your program. From there, when you ask Python to import something, it will find it in the `my_repo` directory (also because they each contain an `__init__.py`, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37139786/11384184)).
Having a correct PYTHONPATH is a simple solution which works for nearly every project.

You can also edit the `sys.path` list when the program starts, but take care that when you `append('..')` it is relative to your current directory `os.curdir`, which may or may not be what you want. It changes depending on how you execute your program.

You can check what you are actually doing by printing both `sys.path` and `os.path.abspath(os.curdir)` at program startup.